# pyCharm: append(int) flagged correctly or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've recently switchedfrom using a text editor to the PyCharm IDE, and while a minimal example is fine:

```
def temp():
    a_list = [[], []]
    value = int(5)
    a_list[1].append(value)
    print(a_list)
```

However for this function:

```
# replays is parsed json data. cache is a caching class for player stats
def team_average_ratings(replays, cache):
    """returns an array containing a dict of the average rating of the green and red teams"""
    team_ratings = []
    for battle in replays:
        teams = [[], []]
        std = battle.get('std')
        for player in std.get('vehicles').values():
            name = player.get('name')
            cached_player = cache.cached_player(name)
            if cached_player:
                rating = int(cached_player.get('global_rating'))
                team_num = player.get('team') - 1 # 1-indexed -> 0-indexed
                if name == std.get('playerName'):
                    # note player's team and eliminate them from the calculation
                    replay_team = team_num
                else:
                    teams[team_num].append(rating)
        team_ratings.append({'green': mean(teams[replay_team]),
                             'red': mean(teams[1 - replay_team])})
    return team_ratings
```

The IDE flags the line:
[image]

This can be rectified by modifying the line to read:

```
list(teams[team_num]).append(rating)
```

however when editing the line, the IDE correctly identifies that `teams[team_num]` is a list.

The code works correctly when run by the interpreter.

Is this a case of my doing something particularly obtuse, or is there a problem with the parser in the IDE?

Comment: its the inspector ... if you add something that is not a list to your `teams` list then it will go away ... but since it only sees lists in there it thinks it can only accept lists and it stupidly doesnt know that you are pointing at the inner list

Comment: @JoranBeasley do you want to make that an answer?